# ORDER BY clause not working in live server properly

Tags: php, sql-order-by

I have developed a php project which contains the table 'test'. The rows are fetched and shown and it is sorted by date column using `ORDER BY` clause in `SQL`query. The following is the block of code used

```
<?php 
      foreach($stmt =$conn->query('SELECT * FROM test JOIN users USING(rollno)
      WHERE rollno='.$userRow['rollno'].' order by date desc')as $row){ ?>
        <button class="accordion"><b>Test on <?php echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime( $row['date'] )); ?></b></button>
          <div class="panel">
           <p>
           <table border="1">
            <?php
            echo "<tr><td>Date: " . date('d-m-Y', strtotime( $row['date'] )) . "</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td>Subject: " . $row['sub'] . "</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td>Topic: " . $row['topic'] . "</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td>Type: " . $row['type'] . "</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td>Total Marks: " . $row['totl_marks'] . "</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td>Marks Obtained: " . $row['marks'] . "</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td>Rank: " . $row['rank'] . "</td></tr>"; ?>
         </table>
            </p>
          </div>
      <?php }?>
```

I want to sort the records such that the newest comes at top. The date stored in the database is in d-m-Y format. The system works fine at localhost, but when the project is made live, the records are not sorted as expected. The date column in database uses `varchar` type. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[STR_TO_DATE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp) function in mysql can make the help. It will first convert date string in database to `date` type and then apply order by.

Order by query should be:

```
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d-%m-%Y') DESC
```

Comment: It is saying unexpected `%`

Comment: Can you run the query independently in mysql console?

Comment: Yes, the query is running fine in mysql console

Comment: can you please post how you run it using php?